# Checking elements in a dataframe and extract some values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check if values in a column contain one word or another (e.g. apple/watermelon) and create a new column (`Fruit`) collecting those values coming from `Sentence`.

For example:

```
Sentence                      Fruit
I bought 1 watermelon        watermelon
I bought 2 apples            apples       
I bought 1 apple             apple
```

I have tried as follows

```
schema = '^(?P<Fruit>\d+ apple?| watermelon?)' but it is not working. If I wrote

schema_n = '^(?P<Fruit>\d+ apple?)
```

or

```
schema_n = '^(?P<Fruit>\d+ watermelon?)
```

it works. 
My question is thus how I could use operator notation to check a value (the fourth element in a string; or condition).

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I'm 100% clear what you're asking--you want to know how to check `(apple|watermelon)` in regex in one shot? (That's the answer). Note that `watermelon?` in regex means that the `n` character is optional, so it's not really working exactly the way you mean it to. Also, anchoring the regex like you're doing with `^` means that it won't match anything in your sample df, so I don't think this is really your code. Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: I have this kind of sentences (I suppose they all have the same structure, i.e. ` word word number word `; there should be rows with other more words at the end). The exercise requires to extract only ` apple ` or ` watermelon ` from the sentences - they are not in general the last words in the strings, so I cannot use `[:1] `. However, I would be also interested in extracting number and word (` watermelon ` or ` apple `)

Comment: sorry for being not clear

Comment: I noticed that watermelon is singular, but apple might be also plural

Comment: sorry for still being not clear. So what I would like to have is in a new column only apple/apples or watermelon, if it is possible also including the number. I will try what you suggested

Comment: an example of output would be or `1 watermelon | 2 apples | 1 apple` or just `watermelon | apples | apple` as in the example shown in the post

Comment: It seems like a combination of np.where, str.split and str.contains could be another option. Not sure if that works for you and if you prefer / require a regex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, it's not entirely clear what logic governs the fruit matching, but if you're trying to extract any `"apple"`, `"apples"` or `"watermelon"` from sentences where the fruit is preceded by a digit and space, you can use:

```
>>> def replacer(s):
...     return re.search(r"(?<=\d )(apples?|watermelon)\b", s).group()
...
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Sentence": ["I bought 1 watermelon", "I bought 2 apples", "I bought 1 apple"]})
>>> df["Fruit"] = df["Sentence"].apply(replacer)
>>> df
                Sentence       Fruit
0  I bought 1 watermelon  watermelon
1      I bought 2 apples      apples
2       I bought 1 apple       apple
```

If your data has rows that don't match the pattern, this will crash. You'd need to check those cases and fill in some default value, say:

```
>>> def replacer(s):
...     match = re.search(r"(?<=\d )(apples?|watermelon)\b", s)
...     return match.group() if match else None
...
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Sentence": ["foo 1 watermelons"]})
>>> df["Fruit"] = df["Sentence"].apply(replacer)
>>> df
            Sentence Fruit
0  foo 1 watermelons  None
```

If your data is more complex than what you've shown, you'll need to adapt this to fit your actual use case.